# Why typescript throw error not assignable to interface against key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why typescript is throw error on `foo`:

```
argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: unknown; }'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'Foo'.
```

`fn` is taking argument of an object with key and value pairs.

`foo` object is also key and value pairs.

the key in `foo` is a string and the value is can be number/string which is `unknown`.

```
const fn = (a: { [key: string]: unknown }) => {};

interface Foo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const foo: Foo = { id: 1, name: 'name' };

fn(foo);
```

So why typescript throw error on that type?

Answer (score 2):

The only strings that are allowed to index here are: `"id"`, and `"name"`. What you specify by using: `[key: string]: unknown` is "indexable by any string". For example the string "potatos". Does your object have a key potatos, or any other possible string? Not really. TypeScript assumes that the function will try to access arbitrary properties, and your interface is two specific (id, name) properties. If you really wanted, you could use `Record<string, any>`, but in any case, you will loose type information and will have to "recoup" it in the function to actually work with the object.

The solution depends on the context what you are trying to do. Some ideas to make this exact example work:

```js
const fn = (a: Record<"id" | "name", unknown> ) => {};
```

```js
const fn = (a: { id: unknown, name: unknown}) => {};
```

Just want access to the id? This should be suficcient:

```js
const fn = (a: { id: number }) => {};
```

The error message comes from the type requirement: `[key: string]: unknown`. And that is indeed not how `Foo` is declared. If you did, it would work:

```js
const fn = (a: { [key: string]: unknown }) => {};

interface Foo {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

const foo: Foo = { id: 1, name: 'name' };

fn(foo);
```

**BTW:** You can always do `foo as unknown as Record<string, unknown>` but that just "shuts up" the compiler.

Comment: But why does it then work with `type`?

Comment: With what type? The interface `Foo`?

Comment: @SSM I've added a bit of extra info. Hope it helps? Otherwise get back to me in the comments

Comment: I mean replacing `interface` with `type` makes it work, like `type Foo = { id: number; name: string }`

Comment: @SSM I... don't know. Since this would be out of scope for this question anyway, I recommend you ask a second one.